# XCode: Still Able To Access Deleted .plist Files...Why?

Tags: xcode, ios5, plist

I noticed something odd today. I have an application that writes/read data to a .plist file, and when I deleted that file and left all my code in my implementation file the same, I ran the application in the simulator and it was still able to read/write data to this deleted file.

However, if I try to read data from this deleted file in another view controller, they cannot find it. Very very strange.

Is this a known issue in Xcode, or is there something I am probably doing wrong?

If I need to provide some sample code I will, just let me know.

Comment: Xcode never deletes a file from the simulator or device. If you remove the app from simulator/device the file will be gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulator loves to do this kind of thing, Try clicking "Reset Content and Settings" in the simulator, and cleaning targets in Xcode command-shift-K. Now if that doesn't completely do it you may have to restart Xcode. Another thing I've noticed when working with a `.plist` is that sometimes if the `.plist` is deleted and the code is intact, when you execute a write command it has created to the `.plist` file to write to.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: I cannot find "Reset Content and Settings" in the simulator. I went under the Settings area and then General then Reset, but it only shows "Reset Location Warnings". Am I looking in the wrong area?

Comment: Dont forget to also do a XCode Clean or else XCode will still find those deleted pList files. Do the simulator reset immediately followed by a clean.

Comment: @Relik Cleaning targets was already mentioned in my answer. You couldn't be more right though!

Comment: Thanks.  This was driving me nuts this morning.  For some reason I always forget to try cmd-shift-K...